# Is a preposition + an adverb a possible pattern in the English language?

Tags: prepositions, sentence-structure, adverbs

Is a preposition + an adverb a possible pattern in the English language?
An example sentence

> I know you from somewhere.

Comment: Yes, but note that modern grammar treats "somewhere" as a compound determinative, not an adverb, though it functions as a head of a noun phrase, and prepositions typically have nouns and noun phrases as complement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This particular adverb can work as a (non-count) **noun** meaning '*a place* not known, named, or specified' or it can start a noun phrase, and that is why it can be used with prepositions, typically combined with *place nouns*:
http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/somewhere

Answer (score 0):

What makes you think that it is not possible? Even [phrase verbs are made from such structure.](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/hail-from-somewhere)

> Joe originally hails from Toronto.

I might have said this hundred of times when I don't want to reveal the source

> I got the news ***from somewhere***